# What is the benefit of becoming a neutron star?

Tags: solar-2

In my first playthrough, I rather ignored the missions (or failed all the ones I attempted...), and just tried to get as big as possible. I was surprised to find that when I "upgraded" to a neutron star, I lost 6 of my planets and my capacity was reduced to 4.

Are there any benefits to becoming a neutron star, short of it just being another step on the way to black hole?

Comment: No idea if it's true or if that's all there is, but [Neutron stars have more mass and therefore do more damage. However, they also are more fragile and take less to destroy. Neutron stars really need some evolved planets to give them a shield, but as long as you have that shield up then you can really destroy things.](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?s=976469c7f3d28bedd4ec298316b382cf&t=1935621&page=4)

Comment: @BenBrocka I was just looking at that same link lol. I also found this one a little earlier which is also just speculation but makes sense "I suspect they're a smaller star with much more gravity than a normal star. And things can be sling-shot around the star much quicker." [link](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=23047874&postcount=4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are benefits to being a neutron star:

- One step closer to being a black hole
- You deal more damage when you ram other objects
- You are smaller and can therefore dodge through smaller gaps (I've never seen this benefit in practice but I've seen others claim it)

There are also disadvantages:

- You can die more easily than a large star since you will explode rather than revert to a smaller star
- You cannot have as many planets as large stars can

I have not seen a clearly stated description of the advantages of a neutron star from an official source, but the developer of the game has replied to the following steam forum discussion with some implications that the 'deal more damage' claim is true: [Is a neutron star worse than a large one?](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1965966&highlight=neutron%20star)

Here are the developers comments from that discussion quoted. The context of the full discussion is helpful for interpreting them.

- Murudai: *Neutron star has it's weaknesses and it's stengths too. So, it is easily destroyed, but have a think about it. How can you fix that problem.*
- Murudai: (in response to "*In other words, a neutron star with an evolution level of over 6 in planets around it can deal huge amounts of damage every time its shield comes up.*") *This. Come on guys, think harder! It's a cleverer game than you think, and if you sit back and plan things you can tackle things much easier.*

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a bit simpler to realize but hard to practice, the increased gravity and smaller size of the neutron star means other systems become your weapons. Pull a large system, build its speed, and launch it at an opponent. The resulting devastation is rather nice, I'm sure there's more but I enjoy making solar rams

Answer (score -1):

The only benefit to a neutron star is that it is possible to become a black hole. Otherwise, a neutron star serves no other purpose.

Answer (score -1):

The Neutron stars have more powerful gravitational field and they hurt more when they bump into things. Unsure whether you can make a multi-star system out of them, but I don't see why not.